# Access LAN behind firewall from internet with OpenVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, openwrt

I have a Home LAN behind a firewall I have no access to and I need to access the devices via their IP addresses from the internet. eg 192.168.2.101 etc

Despite 2 days of reading, I'm struggling, I have a VPS running OpenVPN which I am hoping to use to setup a VPN reverse tunnel.

My LAN router inside the firewall is running OpenWRT, I am thinking I need to setup OpenVPN on this to tunnel out to the VPS, then connect the client to the VPS to access the LAN, is that correct? Does the OpenVPN on the OpenWRT router need to also be configured as a client?

Please help...

Comment: So you have a separate server on another network (with its own ip address) and you want to connect both your LAN (using router) and whatever clients you using elsewhere using that server?

Comment: I may not have explained this very well. I actually want to access some devices on my home LAN from a iphone by their IP address. ie I type the home LAN IP into the phone and connect to say 192.168.2.101 I have openvpn client on the phone, I have a VPS server on the internet with fixed IP running openvpn. My home LAN router is running openwrt. I think what I need is to reverse tunnel through the server to the phone?

Comment: Then you could just set up OpenVPN server on your home network. Properly configured you can access devices on home LAN when connected to your server. Why you have/want a VPS?

Comment: Ahh, well that would be even better but I wasn't sure I would be able to get to the openVPN server on the home LAN via the internet, can you give me a pointer how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure appropriate *routing* for your devices. The server can be configured [push](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans) the relevant routes to your VPN clients or you can configure the routes manually on your clients. On your home LAN you should configure your router with the routes to VPN address block (instead of configuring each device separately) .

For mobile clients your server needs to provide the routing info to your home LAN (192.168.2.0/24 block via OpenVPN server as gateway) and for your home router the info for routes to mobile clients (10.0.8.0/24 or whatever you use as your network via OpenVPN gateway).

Also note that you need to configure IP forwarding on both your OpenVPN server 
and home router.